# Solving a transcendental equation using Lambert's W function

Tags: proof-explanation, problem-solving, lambert-w

I found that transcendental equations with this structure:

$$\ e^{-cx}=a_0(x-r_1) $$

Have this kind of Lambert-W-based solutions:

$$\ x=r_1 + \frac1c\ W \left(\frac{\ ce^{-cr_1}}{a_0}\right) $$

What is the procedure to proof that this is true? I would be thankful if you may help me figure this out.

The formulae were retrieved from: http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/2992274.2992275

Answer (score 2):

Start with the initial equation:
$$e^{-cx}=a_0(x-r_1)$$

Multiply both sides by $\frac{c}{a_0}e^{c(x-r_1)}$:

$$\frac{ce^{-cr_1}}{a_0}=(cx-cr_1)\cdot e^{cx-cr_1}$$

Apply $W$ to both sides:
$$W\bigg(\frac{ce^{-cr_1}}{a_0}\bigg)=cx-cr_1$$
Solve for $x$:
$$x=\frac{1}{c} W\bigg(\frac{ce^{-cr_1}}{a_0}\bigg) +r_1$$
Done!

Comment: Wow, you were fast!

Comment: Thank you so much! I had a feeling that the solution could not be that difficult but I had a hard time trying to figure it out.

Comment: @inghans No problem! There are lots of tricky puzzles involving solving equations with the W function. :)